# Sitelinks In Generic Lising

Tags: seo

I was wondering if anyone know how I can update and categorize my site in the generic Google listing? I noticed sites in Google's generic listing are categorized with specific links under the sites description. How does Google and how would I categorize my site. I have attached screen shot photo:

**Edited**
Better Link: http://www.rimmkaufman.com/rkgblog/2011/05/09/google-sitelinks-video-tip/

Took a day, but I found an answer at a very good site: http://www.seopedia.org/internet-marketing-and-seo/google-sitelinks-the-ultimate-faq/, which hints on how to place sitelinks.

Simply:
What are Sitelinks ? They are a collection of links, automatically chosen by Google’s algorithm, to appear below the result of website, linking to main pages of your website. They are randomly chosen, although you can block any link from appearing.

[image]

Thank you,
deDogs

Comment: So...you've answered your own question? Is there more that you need to understand? That link pretty much sums it up, or provides authoritative links to information that should...

Comment: Since I found an answer, should I leave my question or remove? I updated it for the purpose if anyone else had similar question.

Comment: Shift your answer (for other's benefit) into the answer box: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A very good link,](http://www.rimmkaufman.com/rkgblog/2011/05/09/google-sitelinks-video-tip/) explaining Google's SiteLinks.

Simply: What are Sitelinks ? They are a collection of links, automatically chosen by Google’s algorithm, to appear below the result of website, linking to main pages of your website. They are randomly chosen, although you can block any link from appearing.